# MultipleSelect DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, selection

I have seem some questions similar to this but not exactly this so. Im trying to make multiple selection in a DataGridView with only one column and multiple rows. I want the capability to select and unselect with normal click (without pressing Ctrl) and that the selection remains until I click again. I got

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

        }

        DataGridView1.MultipleSelect = true;
        DataGridView1.SelectMode = GridViewSelectMode.SelectCells;

    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //handle the keep select/unselect group
    }
```

but how do I set up the condition of not using Ctrl key to keep the selection? Thanks

Comment: What happens when you don't want to add a Cell to a selection group but simply move the selection to another Cell?

Comment: You need to click to unselect the unwanted cells. And click again for every cell you want to be in the selection group again.

Comment: That's does not answer the question I asked.

Comment: Then I think I dont understand your question. If you want to move the selection to another cell. You have to unselect the unwanted cell, and select the wanted cells. I dont understand the question sorry.

Comment: Can you reformulate it?

Comment: I guess he wants the user to clcik/unselect each cell.

Comment: All your code is wrong, ie doesn't compile. Very bad style to throw 3 typos in 2 lines at us :-(

Comment: Im guessing I have to deal with CellClick Event. I have tried: 
DataGridView1.Row[e.index].Selected = true; but still...

Comment: @TaW sorry about but style but I dont know what I can add. You are right, I want the user to click/unselect each cell.

Comment: This seems to be harder than expected, probably because it goes againt the UI expectations. According to [this](https://alexmang.com/2009/11/datagridview-keep-cells-selected-as-other-cells-are-clicked/) outdated post one needs to keep a List of selected cells and re-select them upon each click..

Comment: Im gonna check that post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the cells yourself by tweaking a bit the color schemes of the grid and store/remove them in/from a list when they are clicked:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Currently selected cells.
        /// </summary>
        private List<DataGridViewCell> _selectedCells = new List<DataGridViewCell>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /* Just for test
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("A", "ColA");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("B", "ColB");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("C", "ColC");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("D", "ColD");

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("A1","B1","C1","D1");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("A2", "B2", "C2", "D2");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("A3", "B3", "C3", "D3");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("A4", "B4", "C4", "D4");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("A5", "B5", "C5", "D5");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("A6", "B6", "C6", "D6");
            */

            dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
            dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // Edited and added this line to avoid problems when clicking on the header.
            if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0) return;
            // Clears all the selected cells.
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

            if (_selectedCells.Contains(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]))
            {
                _selectedCells.Remove(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]);
                dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
            }
            else
            {
                _selectedCells.Add(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]);
                dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor;
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a charm. This has done the trick perfectly. Very creative idea!

Comment: @JuanJesus You're welcome. Notice I edited and added a new line at the start of the CellClick handler, to manage a click on the header.